# How can I restore a Whatsapp backup while retaining stuff from after the backup?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

For a number of reasons, I just deleted my entire Whatsapp images folder by accident. I backed Whatsapp up yesterday morning, but yesterday night I had a sentimental conversation with a friend about some issues I've been having, and I don't want to lose that either. How can I go about doing this without losing that conversation?

Comment: No you can't(realisticaly).  Recovering data from a deleted folder on a phone might result in a couple bits being recovered with the right tools but not even a sentence of the conversation.

Comment: If that doesn't work then, how can I restore a backup if Whatsapp came with my phone, and thus can't be uninstalled, only disabled?

Comment: your terminology/phrasing does not make sense to me.  I'll take I guess what you mean.  When you restore your phone to factory settings the default apps are not touched at all only the android OS.  If you take to a professional shop $100+ dollars they might be able to recover something but highly unlikely.

Comment: I believe you are wanting to merge to backups is that right?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You actually could have a perfect backup that was automatically created after night conversation and before accidental erasing. Whatsapp creates local backup files at 2 am (up to 7 states), also it saves data to Google Drive (if configured). Check dates of files in `sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases` as well as in Drive interface (again, if Drive backup was configured).
If automated backup was not performed in a desirable timeframe you will need to mess with local backup files and apps reinstallations to get your old, yesterday state, copy images to safe folder and restore a backup with night conversation.
Official FAQ states that you can force an app to restore a particular backup file:

> **To restore a less recent local backup**
>
> Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup
>   files (Google Drive will only have the most recent one). If you wish
>   to restore a local backup which is not the most recent one, you will
>   need to do the following:
>
> 1. Download a file manager app.
> 2. In the file manager app, navigate to `sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases`. If your data is not stored on the SD card, you may see "internal storage"
>      or "main storage" instead of sdcard.
> 3. Rename the backup file you wish to restore from `msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt12` to `msgstore.db.crypt12`. It is
>      possible that an earlier backup may be on an earlier protocol, such as
>      crypt9 or crypt10. Do not change the number of the crypt extension.
> 4. Uninstall WhatsApp.
> 5. Install WhatsApp.
> 6. Tap Restore when asked.

Sources:
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/?category=5245251
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6305834?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en